# Combine different vertical alignments within flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In a flex container, I have another flex container, in which I have two items: content-title and content-body. I'm trying to align them with different vertical alignments. The title has to be to the start of the container with a fixed (responsive) height, the other has to stretch to the available space.

I don't understand how can I do it (if it can be done).
The first item (title) has `align-self: start`, and the content has to stretch (through the property in the parent: `align-content: stretch`).

It's not working as I want because the content is using the space as if both items were stretching. The bodies (content-body) have to be the same height, according to their content.

I don't know if I'm clear. Here is the working code:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaeXzb

Summarizing, I want to stretch vertically 2 items, but keeping the first one with fixed height.

[image]

This is the relevant html:

```
<div class="bodycontent-preview"> 
    <div class="orientItem"><!-- Item 1 -->
        <div class="content-title">
            <h2>Title 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content-body">
            <p>Content body here. Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="orientItem"><!-- Item 2 -->
        <div class="content-title">
            <h2>Title 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content-body">
            <p>Content body here. Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
.bodycontent-preview {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.orientItem {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: stretch;
}
.content-title {
    align-self: flex-start;
}
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove `flex-flow: row wrap;` from `.orientItem`
- Add `flex-grow:1;` to `.content-body`